# How to Open 5 instances of same browser on same machine by using Selenium

Tags: selenium

I want to open 5 instances of same browser in my machine by using Selenium.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Can you share more details about the purpose for this?

Comment: I think you'll want to look into libraries that can parallelize the processes. In Ruby we have tools like https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests.

Answer (score 1):

In Java that would be for instance:

```
WebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriver driver3 = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriver driver4 = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriver driver5 = new FirefoxDriver();
```